# Vue component save data for later

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm trying to store data for later use in vue component.

Data function, example 1

```
data:
function () {
     return {
         username: '',
         phoneNumber: '',
       }    
}
```

Save method

```
var x = JSON.stringify(this.$data)
localStorage.setItem('xxx', x);
```

Load will fail , code:

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('xxx'));
this.$data = x;  // <<< Not working
```

When i will change Data function (add container)

```
data:
function () {
     return {
         container:{
         username: '',
         phoneNumber: '',
       }
     }
}
```

Load works

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('xxx'));
this.$data.container = x.container;  // <<< Works
```

How to not add additional container like in first example

Comment: What's the issue? can you provide details see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: description changed for better clarity, hope that now it's clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't replace `$data` in the way you're attempting to. Instead, try taking advantage of `Object.assign()`:

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('xxx'));
Object.assign(this.$data, x);
```

This should effectively "merge" the data from `x` into `this.$data`, where any properties that match in both objects will have the values in `x` overwrite the values in `this.$data`.